# how can I find directly a basis for $W_1 \cap W_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

> **Problem**:
>   Consider the following subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n};$
>   $W_{1} =\{
> (a; b; c; d) \in \mathbb{R}^{4} : a + c + d = 0\}$
>   and
>   $W_2 =
> \{(a; b; c; d) \in \mathbb{R}^{4}:a+b = 0\, ,\, c = 2d\}$.
>
> Find a basis for $W_1\, ,\, W_2,\,\, W_{1} \cap W_{2} $ and determine their dimensions.
>
> **Here is what I have done**:
>   I wrote as follows
>
> $W_{1} =\{(a; b; c; d) \in \mathbb{R}^{4} : a + c + d = 0\}=\{
> (a; b; c; d) \in \mathbb{R}^{4} : a  = -b-c\}=\{
> (-b-c; b; c; d):\, b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}\}=\{ -c-d(1,0,0,0)+b(0,1,0,0)+ c(0,0,1,0)+ d(0,0,0,1):\, b,c,d\in \mathbb{R} \}=\{ b(0,1,0,0)+c(-1,0,1,0)+  d(-1,0,0,1):\, b,c,d\in \mathbb{R} \}$
>
> **and  with the similar way**
>
> $ W_{2} =\{ b(-1,1,0,0)+d(-1,1,2,1):\, b,d\in \mathbb{R} \}. $
>
> After this, I calculated $W_1 + W_2 $
>   $ W_1 + W_2=\{ b(-1,2,0,0)+c(-1,0,1,0)+  d(-1,0,2,2):\, b,c,d\in \mathbb{R} \} $

On the contrary,

> since 
>   $|W_1 + W_2|=|W_1|+|W_2|-|W_1 \cap W_2|$
>   I can say that 
>   $|W_1 \cap W_2|=2$ so
>   $|W_1\cap W_2|=|W_2|$ 
>   so the bases of the $W_1 \cap W_2$ will be the same as $W_2.$

**But my question is that how can I find directly a basis for $W_1 \cap W_2$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of $W_1$ and $W_2$ is the subspace
$$
W_1\cap W_2 = \{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb R^4: a+c+d=0, a+b=0, c=2d\}.
$$
Substituting $2d$ for $c$ in $a+c+d=0$ gives $a+3d=0$, and substituting $\frac12 c$ for $d$ in $a+c+d=0$ gives $a+\frac32 c=0$. It follows that 
$$
b=-a, \ c=-\frac23 a,\ d=-\frac13 a,
$$
and hence
$$
W = \mathrm{Span}(\{(3, -3, -2, -1) \}).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your final basis for $W_1$ is fine, although you have some typos in the intermediate steps (some instances of $b$ should be replaced by $d$).

Your basis for $W_2$ is fine. Perhaps a neater basis would be $b(-1,1,0,0) + d(0,0,2,1)$.

Your computation for $W_1+W_2$ is not correct; you seem to have just added the vectors corresponding to $b$ together, and [tried to add] the vectors corresponding to $d$ together (it is hard to tell).

It is easiest to avoid $W_1+W_2$ altogether and just write down
$$W_1 \cap W_2 = \{(a,b,c,d) : a+c+d=0, a+b=0, c=2d\}$$
and perform a similar procedure to what you have done for $W_1$ and $W_2$.